# newusers command always return Permission denied, how do I deal with it?

Tags: users

I'm trying to create multiple users accounts in batch and I have full privilege to /etc/passwd

However, this command

```
sudo echo "vv1:myUltraSecretPassword" | newusers
```

always return this error

```
newusers: Permission denied.
newusers: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

I've tried all solutions in post https://superuser.com/q/296373/1100842

such as remove lock file

```
ubuntu@VM-0-17-ubuntu:~$ sudo rm /etc/passwd.lock
rm: cannot remove '/etc/passwd.lock': No such file or directory
ubuntu@VM-0-17-ubuntu:~$ sudo rm /etc/shadow.lock
rm: cannot remove '/etc/shadow.lock': No such file or directory
ubuntu@VM-0-17-ubuntu:~$ sudo rm /etc/group.lock
rm: cannot remove '/etc/group.lock': No such file or directory
ubuntu@VM-0-17-ubuntu:~$ sudo rm /etc/gshadow.lock
rm: cannot remove '/etc/gshadow.lock': No such file or directory
```

and mount remount

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, the `sudo` is needed for the `newusers` command and not the `echo` command.  You are getting that message of cannot lock because `sudo` is not passed from the `echo` command to the `newusers` command.  So, you will need to move the `sudo` to after the `|` before `newusers`.

The layout of the password line in the `echo` command is missing fields, so you probably would have seen error messages like below if you had the `sudo` in the right location

```
newusers: line 1: invalid line
newusers: error detected, changes ignored
```

From the man page for `newusers` we can see it shows all the fields required.

```
DESCRIPTION
       The newusers command reads a file (or the standard input by default)
       and uses this information to update a set of existing users or to
       create new users. Each line is in the same format as the standard
       password file (see passwd(5)) with the exceptions explained below:

       pw_name:pw_passwd:pw_uid:pw_gid:pw_gecos:pw_dir:pw_shell
```

There are 7 fields above so that will mean you need 6 `:`'s.  You need to have all the fields separated by a `:` required to create the new user even if the field is blank.

The command should look like:

```
echo "vv1:myUltraSecretPassword:::::" | sudo newusers
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: or: `sudo newusers < file_with_the_informations`  or  `sudo newusers file_with_the_informations`

Comment: Any idea why incorrectly formatted input causes such a misleading error?

Comment: I didn't write the question.

Comment: It might be more helpful to emphasize the correct use of `sudo` by explaining that first, rather than bury it in an "also".